# NSView or NSApplication event when become inactive

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

A NSStatusItem application,and set NSStatusItem's view as **myView**

```
[statusItem setView:myView];
```

so **myView** can be showed in the status bar, I can toggle a popover by clicking **myView** .
I want to hide the popover when I click the other application, what means , how to get the event when my application is not active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you application delegate you just have to add the following method:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

It will be called immediately before your application is about to deactivated.